# Convert rdd rows into one columns

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am trying to get all the values from Rows into Columns. I don't have an Index, so find it hard to have all in one column.

Code: getting the values

```
traceFilters = sqlContext.read.format("csv").options(header='true', delimiter = ',').load("/data/*.txt")

traceFilters.take(5)
fields = [
 StructField("City", StringType(), False),
 StructField("Country", StringType(), False)
]

traceFilters.track(5)

for row in traceFilters.rdd.collect():
    a =  row.City
    print a
```

This is the data that i am getting from above code:

```
New York
London
Vienna
```

and the result that i want.

`[ New York, London, Vienna ]`

I tried using `transpose`, but its not working and also with `zip`.
Code that i tried:

```
print a.transpose()
```

or     `val1= a.set_index('City').T`

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please post specific code that you've tried so others can make suggestions. This question is too vague.

Comment: @Brian hi, i added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are just printing each value, but that you really want a list. This appends each value into a list, then prints it:

```
traceFilters = sqlContext.read.format("csv").options(header='true', delimiter = ',').load("/data/*.txt")

traceFilters.take(5)
fields = [
 StructField("City", StringType(), False),
 StructField("Country", StringType(), False)
]

traceFilters.track(5)

a = []
for row in traceFilters.rdd.collect():
    a.append(row.City)
print(a)
```

Comment: @Brain Thanks, that's what i wanted. Works like a charm.